# Schutzenberger's evacuation and $\mu$-coefficient of Kazhdan–Lusztig polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux, kazhdan-lusztig

$\def\SYT{\mathrm{SYT}}\def\RSK{\mathrm{RSK}}\DeclareMathOperator\evac{evac}$Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the symmetric group, $\SYT_n$ be the set of standard young tableaux of size $n$.

For $u\in \mathfrak{S}_n$, let $\RSK:\mathfrak{S}_n\to \SYT_n^2$ denote the Robinson-Schensted-Knuth correspondance.

Let $P_{u,w}(q)$ be the Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial and $\mu_{u,w}=[q^{{(l(w)-l(u)-1)}/{2} }]P_{u,w}(q)$.

Let $\evac:\SYT_n\to \SYT_n$ be Schutzenberger's involution.

**Question:** I am looking for a proof of the following proposition that Schutzenberger's involution preserves the $\mu$-coefficient:

> Take $u,w\in \mathfrak{S}_n$, and let $(P_1,Q_1)=\RSK(u)$, $(P_2,Q_2)=\RSK(w)$.  If we set
>   \begin{gather*}
> u'=\RSK^{-1}(\evac(P_1),\evac(Q_1)) \\
> w'=\RSK^{-1}(\evac(P_2),\evac(Q_2)),
> \end{gather*}
>   then we have $$\mu(u,w)=\mu(u',w').$$

Comment: In the title: "evacuation"?

Comment: Perhaps it follows from the fact that evacuation is basically conjugation by $w_0$, which is an automorphism of the Dynkin diagram?

Comment: You say "For $u \in \mathfrak S_n$, let $RSK$ …", but your definition of RSK doesn't refer to $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P^* = evac(P)$. As noted above, if $RSK(u)=(P,Q)$, then $RSK(w_0uw_0) = (P^*,Q^*)$. Conjugation by $w_0$ induces an automorphism of the Hecke algebra sending $T_x \mapsto T_{w_0 x w_0}$ and $c_x \mapsto c_{w_0 x w_0}$, from which the result you want follows. However you might be interested that something stronger is true: if $u=RSK^{-1}(P,Q)$ and $\sigma(u) = RSK^{-1}(P^*,Q)$ then $\mu(u,v)=\mu(\sigma(u),\sigma(v))$. Similarly if $\rho(u) = RSK^{-1}(P,Q^*)$ then $\mu(u,v)=\mu(\rho(u),\rho(v))$.

This follows from a theorem of Mathas on the action of $T_{w_0}$ on cell representations. The relevant paper is [Mathas, On the Left Cell Representations of Iwahori‐Hecke Algebras of Finite Coxeter Groups](https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/54.3.475). Proposition 3.17 is the relevant result.